# how to call javascript function from SmartGWT function

Tags: javascript, gwt, smartgwt, native-code

hi all i am trying to call a native Js function called test i wrote in the HTML file in the smartGWT project but it sayes test is not a function

the native java script code in the smartGWT class :

```
public static native void  callTest()/*-{
        window.test();

}-*/;
```

the java script function in the HTMLfile  :

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">   
    function test(){
        window.alert("test");
    }
    </script>
```

and i also added :

```
<script src="org.example.yourcode.Spiffy.nocache.js"></script>
```

but as i mantaind it sayes test is not a function 
so dos any one have any idea or any one can provide any help please ?
thanx

and when i add $window.test() instead window.test() i get the following message ?

[image]

and when i use $wnd.test(); 
i had the following error :

[image: Error when using $wnd.test()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try adding '**$**' in front of window.test(). i.e. **$window.test()** and see.

Comment: try to run application in different browser.

Comment: i did and i had the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$wnd` instead of `window`.

Comment: i did and i had the the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

GWT JavaScript is loaded in an iframe in the host page, so "window" and "document" in your JavaScript will refer to the iframe. GWT aliases the host page "window" and "document" via `$wnd` and `$doc`.

Please read *all* of this section: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html

Comment: i did but it says null  i added the exception to the question above

Comment: Did you actually look at the log in the DevMode console? Like the error message says? Post the exception that's there.